# The boot screen says that some important files are missing

Tags: boot

I just installed Ubuntu on my Windows 8 PC. When I restarted it first displayed that Windows had encountered an issue and it doesn't know which OS to run. I assumed that was normal and hit enter, now it gave me the choice between windows 8.1 and Ubuntu. I clicked Ubuntu. I don't know why but my PC just restarted. The Dell logo came up and the PC booted. This thing has kept on happening and Ubuntu just doesn't work. I repaired Ubuntu Twice and re downloaded and reinstalled it once.

**The boot screen says that some important files are missing**

### Specs:

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
I have Windows 8.1 running at the moment.
I downloaded the CD from this link
My laptop is the Dell 14R: 1.8 Ghz
                           4 GB ram + 2 GB
Ubuntu is set at 32 GB FYI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either Reinstall Ubuntu  from a new ISO, or go to your boot device menu and ask to use Ubuntu's EFI file